# Vue.js Can't get the data out of a get request into a variable

Tags: javascript, vue.js, request-promise

I am running a server that is serving a Vue.js app.
So if I input http://localhost:9999/ into my browser,
the browser gets 4 important files:
post.js, get.js, vue.js and the index.HTML with the vue code.

I got a dynamic ordered list to work where each list element
has a button to add an element and to remove itself as well as
a debug button which outputs some variables to the console.

Now I need to make a get request to my server to get an Array with JSON data
that will create some elements in a second ordered list.

I tried the following but nothing works:

```
//get("http://localhost:9999/text/1", inputData)
//get("http://localhost:9999/text/1").then(inputData)
//inputData = get("http://localhost:9999/text/1")
```

This is the content of get.js:

```
//which is correctly included in the vue.js index.HTML
//<script SRC="get.js"> </script>
function get(url, params) {
        // Return a new promise.
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            // Do the usual XHR stuff
            var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            req.open('GET', url, true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');

            req.onload = function() {
                // This is called even on 404 etc
                // so check the status
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    // Resolve the promise with the response text
                    //resolve(req.response);
                    resolve(JSON.parse(req.response));
            }
            else {
                // Otherwise reject with the status text
                // which will hopefully be a meaningful error
                reject(req.statusText);
            }
        };

        // Handle network errors
        req.onerror = function() {
            reject("Network Error");
        };

        // Make the request
        req.send(params);
    });
}
```

After the vue.js method block I call

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
    var inputData=[]
    //get("http://localhost:9999/text/1", inputData)
    //get("http://localhost:9999/text/1").then(inputData)
    inputData = get("http://localhost:9999/text/1")
    app.vueData = inputData
    console.log(inputData)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(inputData))
    console.log(';)')
    })
}
```

The Promise has the content but I can't transfer it to the variable.

```
Promise {<pending>}
__proto__: Promise
catch: ƒ catch()
constructor: ƒ Promise()
finally: ƒ finally()
then: ƒ then()
Symbol(Symbol.toStringTag): "Promise"
__proto__: Object
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: Array(4)
0: {text: "This List"}
1: {text: "was pulled"}
2: {text: "from the"}
3: {text: "server"}
length: 4
__proto__: Array(0)
```

---

Since comments get deleted I have to get creative:

@Apal Shah
Thanks for this answer. Your code looks way better than the then() solution.
I got wind of the culprit before reading your solution by adding a lot of console.log()s

```
console.log('app.vueData vor app.vueData = inputData: ')
console.log(app.vueData)

app.vueData = inputData

console.log('inputData nach Zuweisung: ')
console.log(inputData)

console.log('JSON.stringify(inputData)')
console.log(JSON.stringify(inputData))

console.log(';)')
```

Console Output:

```
get block:                                                                  (index):153
app.vueData vor app.vueData = inputData:                                    (index):156
 [__ob__: Observer]                                                         (index):157
  length: 0
  __ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
  __proto__: Array
inputData nach Zuweisung:                                                   (index):161
 [__ob__: Observer]                                                         (index):162
  length: 0
  __ob__: Observer {value: Array(0), dep: Dep, vmCount: 0}
  __proto__: Array
 JSON.stringify(inputData)                                                  (index):164
 []                                                                         (index):165
 ;)                                                                         (index):167

 Download the Vue Devtools extension for a better development experience:   vue.js:9049
 https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools

 You are running Vue in development mode.                   vue.js:9058
 Make sure to turn on production mode when deploying for production.
 See more tips at https://vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html

 (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]                                                   (index):154
  0: {text: "This List"}
  1: {text: "was pulled"}
  2: {text: "from the"}
  3: {text: "server"}
  length: 4
  __proto__: Array(0)
```

Thanks a bunch going to test it now.

The solution is:

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(async function () {

        console.log('get block: ')
        console.log('app.vueData vor app.vueData = get() ')
        console.log(app.vueData)

        //Get is a deferred / asynchronous process / operation
        app.vueData = await get("http://localhost:9999/text/1")

        console.log('app.vueData nach Zuweisung: ')
        console.log(app.vueData)

        console.log('JSON.stringify(app.vueData)')
        console.log(JSON.stringify(app.vueData))
        })

        console.log(';)')
}
```

The caveat was that async had to go in front of function not mounted or this.$nextTick .

Comment: have you tried something like `get("http://localhost:9999/text/1").then(inputData => { console.log(inputData) })` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a Promise which resolves the data after the completion of your HTTP request but your code is not waiting for this promise to resolve.

You can do 2 things:
1. Use `.then()`
2. Use `async`/`await` (I prefer this because it looks clean)

If you want to use async/await,

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(async function () {
    var inputData=[]
    //get("http://localhost:9999/text/1", inputData)
    //get("http://localhost:9999/text/1").then(inputData)
    inputData = await get("http://localhost:9999/text/1")
    app.vueData = inputData
    console.log(inputData)
    console.log(JSON.stringify(inputData))
    console.log(';)')
    })
}
```

In this code, you can see that there is `async` keyword before the function inside `this.$nextTick` and `await` keyword before your get method.

If you want to handle the error, you can always use try/catch block.

```
try {
  inputData = await get("http://localhost:9999/text/1");
} catch (e) {
  console.log(e);
}
```

If you're a fan of `.then()`, your `mounted` method would look something like this,

```
mounted() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
    var inputData=[]
    get("http://localhost:9999/text/1").then(inputData => {
      app.vueData = inputData
      console.log(inputData)
      console.log(JSON.stringify(inputData))
    });
    console.log(';)')
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks have a look at the question again if you are interested because I updated it. :)

Comment: Ohh I didn't see there is a function inside this.$nextTick! I've also updated my answer. But at the end, async/await with try/catch is the best solution which I always use.